# Getting xml content value from a translation file with xpath in library SimpleXML

Tags: php, xpath, attributes, simplexml, translation

I'm programming in the language php and use library SimpleXML to extract language translations from a xml file.

Here is the XML file excerpt from file 'file.xml':

```
<language>
    <translations>
        <string key="key1">This is a first translation</string>
        <string key="key2">This is a second translation</string>    
    </translations>
</language>
```

Now i want to get the xml content value ("This is a first translation") for string with attribute "key1".

With the Code

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');    
$param = $xml->xpath("/language/translations/string[@key='key1']");
```

i get the correct attribute. But i didn't find out how the xpath above must be adapted to get the xml content value. Can you help me?

Comment: Somebody please correct me if I'm wrong: The XPath expression `/language/translations/string[@key='key1']` doesn't return an attribute, it returns an element based on its attribute. The square brackets basically mean "which has" - e.g. `foo[@bar]` is "find me a 'foo' *which has* an attribute 'bar'"

Answer (score 1):

Just cast it as a string:

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath("/language/translations/string[@key='key1']");
$param = (string) $nodes[0];
```

Comment: Thanxs for the first reply.

But if i make a cast from xpath i only got a array in variable $param. But i want to have the text "This is a first translation". Can you help me?

Comment: Ahhh... yeah its going to return an array of nodes even if there is only one. updated answer.

Comment: How can i get text "This is a first translation" then? I know there only exists one node at this point, because the xml string attribute value is unique. I don't understand until now, how i get the content from the xml node.

Comment: I just showed you how to get the text. XPath is always going to return an array so there is no way to do it with xpath. Even if you use the `text()` function as part of your xpath youre still going to get an array back.

Comment: Thanxs. For all people who are reading this topic and now wondering what they could do now here is my solution: i will change the structure from xml file. The translation stands in a seperate children xml tag from xml tag "string". After adapting the xpath statement this will work in my opinion.